# Translucent UINavigationBar flickers when transform is applied in iOS7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, core-animation

In an app I am working on, I'm performing a transition where I'm using a transform to scale a containerView that holds on to the view of a UINavigationController. This transform is tied to a pan gesture recognizer, so depending on the distance of the pan, the transform changes.

On iOS7, the navigationBar is set to be translucent but dark. As I apply the transform, certain values cause the navigationBar to render oddly... see pictures

[image: Rendering correctly]

[image: Rending Incorrectly]

The result is that I get this flickering affect where the navigationBar changes the degree of translucency as the pan occurs. Any idea why this might be?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the code that does it:

```
- (void)handlePanRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{    
    if ([recognizer isEqual:self.panGestureRecognizer])
    {
        if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
            CGFloat xMin        = CGRectGetMidX([self centerContainerFrame]);
            CGFloat xValue      = self.rightContainer.center.x + translation.x;
            [self.rightContainer setCenter:CGPointMake(MAX(xMin, xValue), self.rightContainer.center.y)];
            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];


        CGFloat normalizedTranslation = self.rightContainer.frame.origin.x / self.rightContainer.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat relativeZoom          = (1.0 - self.transformScaleFactor) * normalizedTranslation;
        CGFloat relativeAlpha         = (1.0 - self.minFadeAlpha)         * normalizedTranslation;

        CGAffineTransform transform   = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.transformScaleFactor + relativeZoom, self.transformScaleFactor + relativeZoom);
        CGFloat newAlpha              = relativeAlpha + self.minFadeAlpha;
        [self.centerContainer setTransform:transform];
        [self.centerContainer setAlpha:newAlpha];
    }
```

...etc

Comment: Did you set the navigation bar color directly or by using the appearance proxy?

Comment: Can you post the code of your animation?

Comment: I’m seeing this too – seems to happen when you set the alpha. Doesn’t occur on an iPad 2, which doesn’t do the blur effect. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: no never found a solution unfortunately ... I ended up just using a solid bar. Real downer.